# Ruby fiber additional resume

Tags: ruby

In this example, the fiber is resumed once more to create one more output unexpectedly. The target is to print all the permutation of one array of numbers by iterating through all the possibilities with recursion and print out the result in a fiber.

```
class Fiber
  def self.wrap
    if block_given?
      f=Fiber.new do |*args|
         yield *args
      end
      return lambda{|*args| f.resume(*args) if f.alive? }
    end
  end
end
class FiberIterator
  def initialize
    @fiber_wrap=Fiber.wrap do
        yield
    end
  end
  def each
    while value=@fiber_wrap.call
      yield value
    end
  end
end
def perm(a)
  FiberIterator.new{ permgen(a,a.size) }
end
def permgen (a, n)
    if n == 0 then
       Fiber.yield a
    else
        n.times do |i|
           a[n-1], a[i] = a[i], a[n-1]
           permgen(a, n - 1)
           a[n-1], a[i] = a[i], a[n-1]
       end
    end
end
def printResult (a)
    p a
end

it=perm([1,2,3,4])
for a in it
  printResult(a)
end
```

The result will include an additional 3 after print out all the permutations have been printed. Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `n.times` returns `n`:

```
 1.times { } # => 1
```

and the return value from `permgen` is being caught and evaluated as part of `it` and thus printed out. Too tired atm to go through and fully understand what's yielded or resumed where and when to try and explain how it's getting caught up and printed as if it was a permutation, but you can fix the code by just changing `permgen` to:

```
def permgen (a, n)
  if n == 0 then
    Fiber.yield a
  else
    n.times do |i|
      a[n-1], a[i] = a[i], a[n-1]
      permgen(a, n - 1)
      a[n-1], a[i] = a[i], a[n-1]
    end

    nil # << This is all I added
  end
end
```

---

As a side note, when I ran your code it was printing a `4` not a `3` at the end, based this answer on that being a typo or the result of a different array or playing around with different sized permutations.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. Yeah, error should be 4 instead of 3 since the initial array is [1, 2, 3, 4] instead of [1, 2, 3]. As you said, it should be the n to be returned at the end. Anyway, problem solved.  Appreciated your help.